# DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH is not working in android 2.2. Any other way to detect xhdpi devices in 2.2?

Tags: android

My Application is in Android 2.2. I am trying to calculate density for xhdpi devices.

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int density = metrics.densityDpi;

    if(density == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH){
        TitleIVRLT.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200));
    }
```

but its not allowing me to do that. i checked the Docs and it says that DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH added in API 9. 
So is there any other method to detect xhdpi device in 2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int density = metrics.densityDpi;

if (density == 320) {
   TitleIVRLT.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200));
}
```

because the `DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH` constant value is **320** according to the [Android Doc DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#DENSITY_XHIGH)

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried it already, it worked as well but it would be nice to generalize it.

Comment: I guess this is the only way, or else change your android project to be complied with API **<latest>**